# Rspec controller action not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

test is failing becasue it says the action does not exist, when it clearly does. Is it becasue it is a nested route?  Any thoughts?

Update:

I moved `resources :orders` outside of the nested route and tests passed.  So it has something to do with it being nested.

OrderController

```
def index
    if current_printer
      @orders = Order.all
      @printer = Printer.find(params[:printer_id])
    end
    if current_user
      @orders = Order.where(user_id: params[:user_id])
    end
end
```

OrdersController Spec

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe OrdersController, :type => :controller do
  describe "unauthorized user" do
    before :each do
      # This simulates an anonymous user
      login_with_user nil
      binding.pry
    end

    it "should be redirected back to new user session" do
      get :index
      expect( response ).to redirect_to( new_user_session_path )
    end
  end
end
```

Routes

```
resources :users, only: [:index, :show] do
      resources :orders
end
```

Error

```
Failures:

  1) OrdersController unauthorized user should be redirected back to new user session
     Failure/Error: get :index

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"orders"}
```

Comment: Did you call it `OrderController` or `OrdersController`?  By convention it should be plural.

Comment: No, it has something to do with it being nested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When testing controllers that have nested routes you must pass in a hash of the url params.

for example my routes looked like this

`user_orders GET  /users/:user_id/orders(.:format)    orders#index`

so in my test I passed in a hash with user_id

`get :index, { user_id: 1 }`

Tests passing :)